# LIBXML-RUBY > Xpath context

Tags: ruby, libxml-ruby

**Context:** I'm parsing an XML file using the libxml-ruby gem. I need to query the XML document for a set of nodes using the XPath `find` method. I then need to process each node individually, querying them once again using the XPath `find` method.

**Issue:** When I attempt to query the returned nodes individually, the XPath `find` method is  querying the entire document rather than just the node:

**Code Example:**

```
require 'xml'

string = %{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>}

xml = XML::Parser.string(string, :encoding => XML::Encoding::ISO_8859_1).parse
books = xml.find("//book")
books.each do |book|
    price = book.find("//price").first.content
    puts price
end
```

This script returns `29.99` twice. I think this must have something to with setting the XPath context but I have not figured out how to accomplish that yet.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using Nokogiri for your XML parsing. It's the defacto standard for Ruby.

Comment: I actually started out using Nokogiri and ran into the same exact problem. I switched to libxml-ruby hoping that things would be different there but the same issue persists.

Comment: Well... when the problem follows you you know it's not in the library. :-) Been there, done it too many times to remember. Stick with Nokogiri; It rocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see is `book.find("//price")`.

`//price` means "start at the top of the document and look downward. That's most certainly NOT what you want to do. Instead I think you want to look inside `book` for the first `price`.

Using Nokogiri, I'd use CSS selectors because they're more easy on the eyes and can usually accomplish the same thing:

```
require 'nokogiri'

string = %{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>}

xml = Nokogiri::XML(string)
books = xml.search("book")
books.each do |book|
    price = book.at("price").content
    puts price
end
```

After running that I get:

```
29.99
39.95
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was had incorrectly assumed that would cause the query to start at the top of the node, rather than the document. The issue is resolved by simply removing the "//" in front of price. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Correct. That's one of the reasons I prefer CSS. The slashes in XPath make my brain tired.